# How to do non-blocking Read() for io.PipeRaeder in Golang

Tags: go, nonblocking

I have following code. The executable program will send some text to stdout after 5 seconds. So, in.ReadLine() will block until receive data. How can I set a timeout for ReadLine() or do it in a non-blocking way?

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/path/to/executable")

    stdoutReader, stdoutWriter := io.Pipe()

    cmd.Stdout = stdoutWriter

    cmd.Start()

    in := bufio.NewReader(stdoutReader)
    b, _, _ := in.ReadLine()

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Comment: Read on a pipe blocks.  What is the higher level problem that you are trying to solve?   For example, do you want your program to exit when a line is not received by the timeout?

Comment: I wanto to read the executable output every 10 seconds. If executable send new data, print it out. If not, print a empty string.

Comment: Do the blocking read in its own goroutine and send data (once available) via a channel. Select on that channel and a time.Ticker.

Comment: But the ReaLine() is still blocking right? If I want do ReadLine() every 1 second and print "EMPTY" if no data is recieved. And the executable send "HELLO" every 10 seconds. Instaed of getting 9 "EMPTY" + 1 "HELLO", I will only get 1 "HELLO" right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I figure it out.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan []byte)
    cmd := exec.Command("/path/to/executable")
    stdoutReader, stdoutWriter := io.Pipe()

    cmd.Stdout = stdoutWriter

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return
    }

    in := bufio.NewReader(stdoutReader)

    go func() {
        b, _, _ := in.ReadLine()
        ch <- b
    }()

    complete := false
    for !complete {
        select {
        case s := <-ch:
            fmt.Println(string(s))
            complete = true
        case <-time.After(time.Second * 5):
            fmt.Println("timeout")
            complete = true
        }
    }

}
```